# Determine shift for simple substitution cipher in C

Tags: c, cryptography, frequency-analysis, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to implement a substitution cipher that shifts the alphabet forward three letters to encrypt text.

How can I decrypt the text by comparing actual letter frequencies with average letter frequencies.

The code below produces an array with actual letter frequencies in a crypted text.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char clef[][7] =
{
  ['A'] = "X",
  ['B'] = "Y",
  ['C'] = "Z",
  ['D'] = "A",
  ['E'] = "B",
  ['F'] = "C",
  ['G'] = "D",
  ['H'] = "E",
  ['I'] = "F",
  ['J'] = "G",
  ['K'] = "H",
  ['L'] = "I",
  ['M'] = "J",
  ['N'] = "K",
  ['O'] = "L",
  ['P'] = "M",
  ['Q'] = "N",
  ['R'] = "O",
  ['S'] = "P",
  ['T'] = "Q",
  ['U'] = "R",
  ['V'] = "S",
  ['W'] = "T",
  ['X'] = "U",
  ['Y'] = "V",
  ['Z'] = "W"

};

double frequencyEn[] = {
    .082, .015, .028, .043, .127, .022,
    .020, .061, .070, .002, .008, .040,
    .024, .067, .075, .019, .001, .060,
    .063, .091, .028, .010, .024, .002,
    .020, .001 };

enum { MAX_CLEF = sizeof(clef) / sizeof(clef[0]) };

static char *prompt(FILE *fp, const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
  printf("%s", prompt);
  fflush(0);
  return fgets(buffer, buflen, fp);
}

static void substitute(FILE *fp, const char *buffer, const char *pad1, const char *pad2)
{
  int c;
  const char *pad = pad1;
  int col = 0;
  for (int i = 0; (c = buffer[i]) != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (col == 0)
    {
      fputs(pad, fp);
      col += strlen(pad);
      pad = pad2;
    }

    col++;
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c < MAX_CLEF && clef[c][0] != '\0')
    {
      fputs(clef[c], fp);
      col += strlen(clef[c]);
    }
    else
    {
      putc(c, fp);
      col++;
    }
    if (col > 72)
    {
      putc('\n', fp);
      col = 0;
    }
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  char * buffer = 0;
  char * cryptText = 0;
  long length;
  FILE * plainTextFile = fopen ("plaintext.txt", "rb");
  FILE * cipherTextFile = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "w+");
  char string[100];
  int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
  int accum = 0;

  if (plainTextFile)
  {
    fseek (plainTextFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (plainTextFile);
    fseek (plainTextFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length);
    if (buffer)
    {
      fread (buffer, 1, length, plainTextFile);
    }
    fclose (plainTextFile);
  }

  if (buffer)
  {
    printf("%s", buffer);
  }
  else {
    printf("failure");
  }

  substitute(cipherTextFile, buffer, "", "     ");

  if (cipherTextFile)
  {
    fseek (cipherTextFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (cipherTextFile);
    fseek (cipherTextFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    cryptText = malloc (length);
    if (cryptText)
    {
      fread (cryptText, 1, length, cipherTextFile);
    }
    fclose (cipherTextFile);
  }

  if (cryptText)
  {
    printf("%s", cryptText);
  }
  else {
    printf("failure");
  }

  while ( cryptText[c] != '\0' )
   {

      if ( cryptText[c] >= 'a' && cryptText[c] <= 'z' ){
         count[cryptText[c]-'a']++;
         accum++;
      }

      else if (cryptText[c] >= 'A' && cryptText[c] <= 'Z'){
          count[cryptText[c]-'A']++;
          accum++;
      }
      c++;
   }

   for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
   {
      if( count[c] != 0 )
          printf( "%c %f\n", c+'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);


   }


}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: this is known as Caesar cipher. There is no need to do any frequency analysis to break it.

Comment: I don't know why others are so desperately uninterested but I think it is a good question, although it might fit better elsewhere here. What you can easily do by eyeballing is a bit harder for the computer. What you can do is to sort the values and take the character with the highest frequency as the `e`, the second one as the `a` and so on. It will get quite uncomfortable if there are not enough individual letters in the encrypted text and/or the text is very short.

Comment: Short algorithm hint: Determine letter frequencies in the ciphered text into an array. "Shift" that array over the LF array of your language. In every position of the shifted array, calculate the sum of all the deviations between the LF of the cipher and your known LFs. The position with the least deviation might be the Cesar's offset. (Note this might not work with Latin... That has different LFs)

Comment: `static char clef[][7] =
{
  ['A'] = "X", ['B'] = "Y", ...` looks like incorrect code.  Suspect you want something like `static char clef[][7] =
{
  ['A' - 'A'] = "X", ['B' - 'A'] = "Y", ...`   and `clef[c]` --> `clef[c-'A']`

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea suggested by [tofro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5785362/tofro) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458053/determine-shift-for-simple-substitution-cipher-in-c#comment66237865_39458053) is sound.

The [Chi-Squared Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) computes the sum of the squares of the differences between the expected value, *E<sub>i</sub>*, and the observed value, *O<sub>i</sub>*, divided by the expected value.  The Wikipedia page even mentions an application:

> In cryptanalysis, chi-square test is used to compare the distribution of plaintext and (possibly) decrypted ciphertext. The lowest value of the test means that the decryption was successful with high probability.

Applying that to the problem on hand, you've provided a table of the expected frequencies of different letters in ordinary English text.  We need a program to apply the Caesar Cipher to a given plaintext (or ciphertext):

#### `ec97.c`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// #include "stderr.h"
void err_setarg0(const char *argv0);
void err_usage(const char *usestr);
void err_error(const char *errmsg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char  *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc != 2)
        err_usage("offset");
    int offset = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;
    if (offset < 0)
        err_error("Offset should be a positive number 1..25\n");

    while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)
    {
        char *ptr = buffer;
        unsigned char u;
        while ((u = (unsigned char)*ptr++) != '\0')
        {
            if (isupper(u))
                u = (u - 'A' + offset) % 26 + 'A';
            else if (islower(u))
                u = (u - 'a' + offset) % 26 + 'a';
            putchar(u);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

// Minimal stderr.c code
static const char *arg0 = "unknown";
void err_setarg0(const char *argv0)
{
    arg0 = argv0;
}
void err_usage(const char *usestr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s %s\n", arg0, usestr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
void err_error(const char *errmsg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", arg0, errmsg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Example use (program `ec97`):

```
$ ec97 3 <<< 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!'
Wkh txlfn eurzq ira mxpshg ryhu wkh odcb grj!
$ ec97 23 <<< 'Wkh txlfn eurzq ira mxpshg ryhu wkh odcb grj!'
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!
$
```

And we need a program which:

1. Counts the frequencies of the letters in the input, F<sub>l</sub>, ignoring case, plus the total number of letters, N, in the input.
2. For each possible key, computes the Χ² value using the F<sub>i</sub> value as the *O<sub>i</sub>* and the letter frequency, L<sub>i</sub>×N as *E<sub>i</sub>*, with some careful dinking with the subscripts.
3. Find the smallest Χ² value; it is almost certainly the correct encryption key.

Or, in code:

#### `dc97.c`

```
/* Determine shift used for text encrypted using Caesar Cipher */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Letter frequencies a-z in English */
static const float freq_en[] =
{
    .082, .015, .028, .043, .127, .022,
    .020, .061, .070, .002, .008, .040,
    .024, .067, .075, .019, .001, .060,
    .063, .091, .028, .010, .024, .002,
    .020, .001
};

int main(void)
{
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    size_t freq[26] = { 0 };
    size_t count = 0;

    while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)
    {
        char *ptr = buffer;
        unsigned char u;
        while ((u = (unsigned char)*ptr++) != '\0')
        {
            if (isalpha(u))
            {
                count++;
                freq[tolower(u) - 'a']++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(buffer);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No data read!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    double chisq[26];
    for (int shift = 0; shift < 26; shift++)
    {
        chisq[shift] = 0.0;
        for (int letter = 0; letter < 26; letter++)
        {
            int index = (shift + letter) % 26;
            double delta = freq[index] - count * freq_en[letter];
            chisq[shift] += (delta * delta) / (count * freq_en[letter]);
        }
        printf("'%c' = %13.6f\n", shift + 'A', chisq[shift]);
    }

    int min_i = 0;
    double val_i = chisq[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (chisq[i] < val_i)
        {
            val_i = chisq[i];
            min_i = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Best match is (%d) '%c' = %10.6f\n", min_i, min_i + 'A', val_i);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Testing

Example run:

```
$ ec97 3 <<< 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!' | dc97
'A' =    143.784398
'B' =    564.772479
'C' =    125.131609
'D' =     87.069134
'E' =    178.249272
'F' =     90.994048
'G' =    194.326935
'H' =    301.117365
'I' =    710.786241
'J' =    147.377473
'K' =    304.179348
'L' =    243.699823
'M' =    137.639230
'N' =    183.885553
'O' =    135.720804
'P' =    106.261239
'Q' =    196.046792
'R' =    506.812184
'S' =    517.893291
'T' =    106.267925
'U' =    375.525078
'V' =    202.806561
'W' =    116.660543
'X' =    304.590809
'Y' =    364.746822
'Z' =    139.113568
Best match is (3) 'D' =  87.069134
$
```

I also ran it on the program source code, and the makefile in the directory, and
a couple of data files.  The first is a piece of nonsense often called ['The Great Panjandrum'](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Grand_Panjandrum):

```
So she went into the garden
to cut a cabbage-leaf
to make an apple-pie
and at the same time
a great she-bear coming down the street
pops its head into the shop
What no soap
So he died
and she very imprudently married the Barber
and there were present
the Picninnies
and the Joblillies
and the Garyulies
and the great Panjandrum himself
with the little round button at top
and they all fell to playing the game of catch-as-catch-can
till the gunpowder ran out at the heels of their boots
```

and the second is crafted carefully for this question:

```
Bond was on a roll, playing jazz on his sax.
In all of his doings, nothing was as bad as what was going on now,
but nary a jocular hint did his writing contain that
all was not going as his boss though it would.
Quit? Zounds!  No way to quit now.
```

There are no e's in that, which, it might be thought, could throw things off, but there isn't a problem, it seems.

```
$ x=$(random 1 25)
$ ec97 $x < great.panjandrum
Uq ujg ygpv kpvq vjg ictfgp
vq ewv c ecddcig-ngch
vq ocmg cp crrng-rkg
cpf cv vjg ucog vkog
c itgcv ujg-dgct eqokpi fqyp vjg uvtggv
rqru kvu jgcf kpvq vjg ujqr
Yjcv pq uqcr
Uq jg fkgf
cpf ujg xgta kortwfgpvna octtkgf vjg Dctdgt
cpf vjgtg ygtg rtgugpv
vjg Rkepkppkgu
cpf vjg Lqdnknnkgu
cpf vjg Ictawnkgu
cpf vjg itgcv Rcplcpftwo jkougnh
ykvj vjg nkvvng tqwpf dwvvqp cv vqr
cpf vjga cnn hgnn vq rncakpi vjg icog qh ecvej-cu-ecvej-ecp
vknn vjg iwprqyfgt tcp qwv cv vjg jggnu qh vjgkt dqqvu
$ ec97 $x | dc97
'A' =   3403.710518
'B' =   1821.123417
'C' =     29.719952
'D' =   5238.969620
'E' =   2077.413735
'F' =   8274.966485
'G' =   2446.331525
'H' =   8950.309208
'I' =   1362.257963
'J' =   4419.368172
'K' =   3161.502276
'L' =   3113.030682
'M' =   7778.647756
'N' =   1112.302912
'O' =   1497.782346
'P' =   1490.896824
'Q' =  10395.032795
'R' =   1985.696886
'S' =   2382.319358
'T' =   4874.708427
'U' =   3280.570608
'V' =   1467.488275
'W' =   7318.221432
'X' =   5634.124795
'Y' =   3108.392584
'Z' =   2849.154134
Best match is (2) 'C' =  29.719952
$ echo "Key = $x"
Key = 2
$

$ x=$(random 1 25)
$ ec97 $x < bond.jazz
Ylka txp lk x olii, mixvfkd gxww lk efp pxu.
Fk xii lc efp alfkdp, klqefkd txp xp yxa xp texq txp dlfkd lk klt,
yrq kxov x glzrixo efkq afa efp tofqfkd zlkqxfk qexq
xii txp klq dlfkd xp efp ylpp qelrde fq tlria.
Nrfq? Wlrkap!  Kl txv ql nrfq klt.
$ ec97 $x < bond.jazz | dc97
'A' =   2630.974532
'B' =   2107.704681
'C' =   1473.828862
'D' =    865.368278
'E' =    715.940980
'F' =   1010.885486
'G' =   2881.481606
'H' =   3297.014998
'I' =   1302.909485
'J' =    871.665974
'K' =    917.232399
'L' =   2716.342024
'M' =   2525.973294
'N' =   2077.065275
'O' =   3096.667665
'P' =   2211.782909
'Q' =   1793.302623
'R' =   1427.340376
'S' =   1537.934006
'T' =    702.667000
'U' =   3489.590647
'V' =   3111.999371
'W' =   1445.825861
'X' =    142.412135
'Y' =   2671.998367
'Z' =   1977.131986
Best match is (23) 'X' = 142.412135
$ echo "Key = $x"
Key = 23
$
```

It seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I was trying to implement your code in `c++` but getting different result for your sample string **The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!**. can you please take a look and see what I am doing wrong? [Here](https://repl.it/@ahashans/ceaserCipher) is the link for the code.

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib: Thanks for pointing me at this answer of mine — I'd been looking for the code it contains, but hadn't found it (even though it is there in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) Git repository).  When I run my code (`dc97`) on the unencrypted string, I get the same output as you do (not a strong preference for 'A' over 'C').  What I show above is the output from `ec97` shifting the string by 3.